# Does anyone know of any specific "eutactic hyperstars"?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

To the best of my recollection, the "eutactic stars" discussed by Coxeter in Regular Polytopes all yield projections from n-dimensional hypersolids (n > 3) to their "shadows" as familiar solids in 3-space.

Does anyone know of any "eutactic hyperstars" which fulfill the same role between j- and k-space, for j > k > 3 ?

I would be particularly interested in any such cases where j = 8 and k = 6, because I think they might shed light on whether there is an answer to a question which I recently posted:

[Does a 4_21 exist with 4 vertices from each of of 24 1_22's and 6 from each of 24 "octadeca-diminished" 1_22's (all 48 mutually disjoint)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528109/does-a-4-21-exist-with-4-vertices-from-each-of-of-24-1-22s-and-6-from-each-of-2)